# getting alertify to work with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, turbolinks, alertify

I am trying to use turbolinks in a rails 3 app. Everything is fine, except that Alertify stops working after a page change.

I have installed the jquery-turbolinks gem to patch it up, but this has had no effect.

I have also tried wrapping the alertify function and triggering it on page:change, but again no joy.

Anyone have issues with turbolinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who encounters this with Alertify 0.4.0 (currently RC1) can solve this by reseting the Alertify elements you're using. In my case, it was Alertify.dialog:

```
Alertify.dialog.el = false
// Do your normal JS stuff
```

In my crude understanding of this, Alertify thinks that a dialog element has been created, but when Turbolinks loads a page, it destroys that element. We need to tell Alertify it has been destroyed and Alertify will recreate it.

If you need any help with specifics, let me know.

Comment: You saved my day! Just a heads-up for anybody going from alertify 3.x to 4, `alertify` no longer lives in the global namespace. If you want everything to work again as before, add this `alertify = Alertify.dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Turbolinks messes with the global scope, which prevents the alerts being properly connected with the DOM.

My work around is thus:

```
   //Keep global reference to alertify init() function
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
     window alertifyInit = alertify.init;
    });
    //re-initialise on page change/load
    $(document).on('page:change page:load',function(){
        alertifyInit();
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The fix resulted in another error where the old alertify instance was referenced and could not be found.